# Close Internet Window

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am loading a page from a button press event and depending on the credentials of the person loading the page, they may be re-directed to a secondary page.  I just discovered that the below no longer works if the user is re-directed.  How in IE & Chrome can I close the window if a redirect occurs?

This works if no redirect happens

```
string close = @"<script type = 'text/javascript'>
  window.returnValue = true;
  window.close();
</script>";
base.Response.Write(close);
```

Comment: You can't because scripts can only close Windows that were opened by them once the window changes it no longer originated from the script and therefore can't be closed by it. A script cannot even close its own window. At least not in the latest version of chrome. Theoretically your code above shouldn't work in the newest versions of chrome because that would be a script trying to close its own window and the window.returnValue seems to be depreciated are you sure it's still in use?

Comment: @Binvention - 200%, I use it daily.  It works perfectly except for the Response.Redirect().

Comment: But are you using the latest version of chrome because it's been removed from the Mozilla web documentation as depreciated (or at least the function that uses it window.showModalDialog is depreciated.) and you can look at the window.close() documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Comment: It it currently works for you then the one thing you could try is controlling the redirect from the parent window rather then the created window that way it still has a script origin

Comment: Another option would be to use an iframe window rather then a full window to log in/redirect

Comment: Ps I just tried using window.returnValue to allow the window to be closed by script and it didn't work in chrome 48

Comment: @Binvention - how would I do it with an iframe?

Comment: Make your iframe fixed positioning and the size of your current window control or whatever size you want at which point window messenger can be used  to pass information between the two and you can use the window reference in the parent window to control the iframe redirects and close it.

Comment: @Binvention - I have never worked with iframes, I will google this option and post back if success/fail

Comment: With new security measures constantly being put in place  it's harder to control Windows from other Windows. And to help out go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: And keep in mind that the window api for the iframe is the same as the window api for your current window it just has different permissions